# Trying to set axml values after running xamarin androd app but wont access method needed

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm trying to follow this tutorial and implement the weather to show once my alarm has activated but it never goes into the `OnPostExecute` method to set the axml values to the values it has grabbed from my coordinates.

Tutorial - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-make-a-weather-app/

My code -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Locations;
using Android.Media;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.IO;
using Square.Picasso;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Support.V4.Content;
using Android;
using Android.Util;

namespace INFT_Assignment_1
{
    [Activity(Label = "AlarmActivated", ShowForAllUsers = true)]
    public class AlarmActivated : Activity, ISerializable, ILocationListener
    {
        private Button okalarm;
        LocationManager locationManager;
        string provider;
        static double lat, lng;
        OpenWeatherMap openWeatherMap = new OpenWeatherMap();
        readonly public int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 0;


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_alarm);
            // Create your application here

            //ask for permissions
            if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation)!= Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
            {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this,new String[] { Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation }, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
            else
            {
                //Permission is granted
            }

            okalarm = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.okalarm);
            okalarm.Click += delegate
            {
                MainActivity.player.Stop();
                this.StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
            };

            MainActivity.player = MediaPlayer.Create(Application.Context, RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Ringtone));
            MainActivity.player.Start();

            //weather code starts here


            locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);
            provider = locationManager.GetBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);
            Location location = locationManager.GetLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if (location == null) System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("No Location");


        }


        public override void OnAttachedToWindow()
        {

            Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.ShowWhenLocked |
                            WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn |
                            WindowManagerFlags.DismissKeyguard |
                            WindowManagerFlags.TurnScreenOn);
        }
        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
        }
        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();
            locationManager.RemoveUpdates(this);
        }
        public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            lat = Math.Round(location.Latitude, 4);
            lng = Math.Round(location.Longitude, 4);
            new GetWeather(this, openWeatherMap).Execute(Common.APIRequest(lat.ToString(), lng.ToString()));
        }
        public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider) { }
        public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider) { }
        public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, [GeneratedEnum] Availability status, Bundle extras) { }
        private class GetWeather : AsyncTask<string, Java.Lang.Void, string>
        {
            TextView txtCity, txtLastUpdate, txtDescription, txtHumidity, txtTime, txtCelsius;
            private ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(Application.Context);
            private MainActivity activity;
            OpenWeatherMap openWeatherMap;
            private AlarmActivated alarmActivated;
            ImageView imgView;


            public GetWeather(AlarmActivated alarmActivated, OpenWeatherMap openWeatherMap)
            {
                this.alarmActivated = alarmActivated;
                this.openWeatherMap = openWeatherMap;
            }

            protected override void OnPreExecute()
            {
                base.OnPreExecute();
                pd.Window.SetType(Android.Views.WindowManagerTypes.SystemAlert);
                pd.SetTitle("Please wait....");
                pd.Show();
            }
            protected override string RunInBackground(params string[] @params)
            {
                string stream = null;
                string urlString = @params[0];
                Helper http = new Helper();
                urlString = Common.APIRequest(lat.ToString(), lng.ToString());  
                stream = http.GetHTTPData(urlString);
                return stream;
            }
            protected override void OnPostExecute(string result)
            {
                base.OnPostExecute(result);
                if (result.Contains("Error: Not City Found"))
                {
                    pd.Dismiss();
                    return;
                }
                Log.Debug("SO", "tTESTESTESTESTESTSETESTESTSETESTESTESTESTESTESTESTESTESTESTEStTESTESTESTESTESTSETESTESTSETESTESTESTESTESTESTESTESTESTESTES");
                openWeatherMap = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OpenWeatherMap>(result);
                pd.Dismiss();
                //Controls   
                txtCity = activity.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCity);
                txtLastUpdate = activity.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtLastUpdate);
                txtDescription = activity.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtDescription);
                txtHumidity = activity.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtHumidity);
                txtTime = activity.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtTime);
                txtCelsius = activity.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCelsius);
                imgView = activity.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);
                //Add Data   
                txtCity.Text = $"{openWeatherMap.name},{openWeatherMap.sys.country}";
                txtLastUpdate.Text = $"Last Updated:{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy HH: mm ")}";
                Log.Debug("SO", "LOGGING - " + txtHumidity.Text);
                txtHumidity.Text = $"Humidity: {openWeatherMap.main.humidity} %";
                Log.Debug("SO", "LOGGING - " + txtHumidity.Text);
                txtTime.Text = $"{Common.UnixTimeStampToDateTime(openWeatherMap.sys.sunrise).ToString("HH: mm ")}/" +
                               $"{Common.UnixTimeStampToDateTime(openWeatherMap.sys.sunset).ToString("HH: mm ")}";
                txtCelsius.Text = $"{openWeatherMap.main.temp} °C";
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(openWeatherMap.weather[0].icon))
                {
                    Picasso.With(activity.ApplicationContext).Load(Common.GetImage(openWeatherMap.weather[0].icon)).Into(imgView);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue can you explain a little please?

Comment: When the alarm is activating the resource variables aren’t changing values to the weather information. I can’t work out whether or not the gps isn’t finding any coordinates to actually gather the data or if there’s a problem with how I’m setting them.

Comment: Then why not debug the onlocationChanged method to check whether or not its working